# Что значит эта запись при создании миграции?

Tags: база-данных, laravel, миграция

Помогите понять что значит эта записи в миграции ?
И что за 'user_id_fk_1001484' ?

```
$table->foreign('user_id', 'user_id_fk_1001484')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: 1. Изучите понятие внешних ключей в SQL. 2. Изучите документацию по созданию миграций в laravel. Тогда всё станет понятно

Comment: по данной ссылке вы моете прочитать что это значит
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints